# UIDatePicker draw time to another color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

I have UIDatePicker and I want to draw time in UIDatePicker for example in gray color

I need this, if in my graphic is draw some interval, so in datePicker user can't select this time

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you, but `UIDatePicker` doesn't support setting valid time ranges like what you described. The only options are minimum and maximum dates. You need to build a custom control from scratch if you really need this and that will cost a lot of effort.

Comment: but, how about draw time in UIDatePicker to another color?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my solution, I can draw time to another color

```
for (UIView *view in datePicker.subviews) {
        for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
            for (UIView *subSubView in subView.subviews) {
                for (UIView *thirdSubView in subSubView.subviews) {
                    for (UILabel *label in thirdSubView.subviews) {
                        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                            label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I need to catch event when scrolling DatePicker, I doing this, and this work, but I break the scroll

```
for (UIView *view in datePicker.subviews) {
        for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
            Class UIPickerTableView = objc_getClass("UIPickerTableView");

            if ([subView isKindOfClass:UIPickerTableView]) {
                UITableView *sub = (UITableView *) subView;
                sub.delegate = self;
            }
            for (UIView *subSubView in subView.subviews) {
```

[image]

I try doing another way, but it doesn't work

```
for (UIView *view in datePicker.subviews) {
        for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
            Class UIPickerTableView = objc_getClass("UIPickerTableView");

            Method targetMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIPickerTableView, @selector(scrollViewDidScroll:));
            Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIPickerTableView, @selector(__scrollViewDidScroll:));
            method_exchangeImplementations(targetMethod, newMethod);

            for (UIView *subSubView in subView.subviews) {
```

Comment: So this is your answer for your own question? Does this work for you?

Comment: I can change label color in DatePicker, but I can't catch action when DatePicker scrolling